# Hello Guys I am new in joomla and I want to display search module in header using code

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

Hello I am new in Joomla and I need help

I just want to display my new module into my header.php file I try with

but I don't see any search form in my header. Can anyone help me step by step thanks in advance

**Note:** create new module from my Joomla admin using default search module new module name = Header Search Module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="your-position-name" />` in the file you want to display that module. Have you tried this?